# Randomizing whole deck and pick the first or randomly pick from deck?

Tags: statistics

I have a deck of sorted cards(*n*-cards).

I have two way to pick card from this deck.

**Way-1** : Randomizing the whole deck every time before picking up and then pick the first one.

**Way-2** : Randomly pick any card.

Both are random but which is more random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases all cards will have equal probability to become the picked card.

So there is no essential difference.